# the value of the field Main.Activity.b1 is not used

Tags: onclicklistener

can some one help me out im trying the onclick  android tutorial how how to change pages with a button but im stuck im getting an error that says the value of the field Main.Activity.b1 is not used i cant figure it out

```
       package com.example.lasttry;

            package com.example.lasttry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
private Button b1;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.lasttry";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.b1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.b1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
public void sendMessage(View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b1); 
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourSecondActivityClass.class);
    startActivity(i);       

        }
    });
```

You can place this code to your onCreate method. So whenever user clicks the button, your app open up a new activity instance based on yourSecondActivityClass. This class must be the type of Activity, and you must define this activity in Manifest file.